# jQuery - dynamically switch Select Menu to Multiple

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a normal `select` menu with a few options.
I'd like to use jquery to change it to have `multiple="multiple"`.
I intend to use a checkbox to toggle it.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"> Toggle Select
<br>
<select name="targets" id="targets">
<option value="0">-----Select a Target----</option>
<option value="1">Target 1</option>
<option value="2">Target 2</option>
<option value="3">Target 3</option>
</select>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#toggle").on('click',function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')==true){ 
         $("#targets").attr('multiple',true).attr('height',90);
        }else{
         $("#targets").attr('multiple',false).attr('height',0);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

The height seems to be ignored.
Can `<select>` menus toggle the `multiple="multiple"` attribute effectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are toggling the multiples just fine. If you are really trying to change the height of a `select` box you need to use the attr `size` not height.

Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R8A7g/

Just change the size attr in the JS to change the height around.

Comment: Nice Job showing an alternative to multiple selected options with the Ctrl button.  I just may use that.